# Namespace issues with auto-generated file

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-3.5

After adding to a large Web application a reference to a Web service, the auto-generated Reference.cs is stopping my project from building. Here is the error:

```
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'XXXXXServiceReference' does not exist in the namespace 'Oranges.Oranges' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\XXXXX\Service References\XXXXXServiceReference\Reference.cs
```

The problem is stemming from the organization of this legacy system. There is a namespace with the same name as the default namespace. So there is a large section declared under namespace: "Oranges.Oranges" for instance. I didn't do it and it's not changing. Bummer.

So when the auto-gen code calls Oranges.XXXXXServiceRequest, ASP.NET looks for XXXXXServiceRequest in Oranges.Oranges and doesn't find it, causing errors.

So I need a way to change the auto-generation or the way ASP.NET is assigning namespaces to this section. I can't risk killing this automatic namespace assumption if it's used elsewhere. This is a very large Web app and I haven't worked on it long.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So I found yet another namespace with the name "Oranges". That makes at least three namespaces with the same name. Now when I am in "Oranges.Admin", I have to call global::Oranges.Oranges.XXXXXServiceReference or else it looks in "Oranges.Admin.Oranges" because that namespace exists.

Answer (score 1):

Bummer is right.

**BAD SOLUTION:**  Edit your auto-generated service reference code and add some well-placed `global::` keywords in there.  Do this every time you re-generate the code.

*Note: I feel dirty for even suggesting this.  Pleeease be gentle.*

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've got so far. But I'm a third-party developer; when another developer regenerates, my solution is gone. We'll say this is my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

1.You may press F2 to rename namespace.

2.Click properties in the solution management and modify default namespace.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't override project-wide. That will break other stuff on this huge project and I'm not the only one accessing it.